# How to sinon stub a call to external module in a tested function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

I am testing a function. That function has a call to an external module which makes my test fail:

```
element.funcCall();
```

Where the function looks like this:

```
function funcCall() {
    external.a.b.c.doSomething();
}
```

It fails on: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'external.a.b.c.doSomething')

How can I stub or fake this so the call is not really make. I do not need it's functionality for this test.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I do this kind of thing:

```
var element  = require('element'),
    external = require('external'),
    sinon    = require('sinon'),
    expect   = require('chai').expect;

describe('element.funcCall()', function() {

    before(function() {
        this.doSomethingStub = sinon.stub(external.a.b.c, 'doSomething');
    });

    it('should do something external', function() {
        element.funcCall();
        expect(this.doSomethingStub.called).to.be.true;
    });

    after(function() {
        this.doSomethingStub.restore();
    });

});
```

Comment: Tried but kept getting the same error. I ended up solving it a different way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I ended up solving this. Since I did not care about that external function being executed, I faked it like so:

```
var func = function() {};
external = 
   { a: 
      { b: 
         { c: 
            {doSomething: func}
          }
       }
   }

...
element.funcCall();
expect.....
```

This was the internal function call was redirected to en empty function and I could test the rest of the method

Comment: can i have a implementation for that fake calls and Test Case